# dplyr summarise_each() using multiple functions for different column subsets across the same groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use `summarise_each()` to apply multiple functions to a grouped dataset.  However, rather than apply each function to *all* columns, I'd like to apply each function to particular subsets.  I realize I could do this by specifying each column with `summarise()`, but I have many variables.

Is there an alternate solution to either 1) using `summarise_each()` and then deleting the unneeded columns or 2) saving the `group_by()` result, performing multiple separate `summarise_each()` operations and combining the results?

If this is not clear, let me know and I can try to illustrate with some example code.

Comment: I do suggest you do illustrate with sample data, sample output, and code you tried/have.

Comment: In that case, loop through the columns of interest and do the `summarise` with `lapply` or use `Map` with corresponding functions for corresponding columns of interest

Comment: regarding your question "1) using summarise_each() and then deleting the unneeded columns" you can specify within `summarise_each` which columns should not be used (but note that they will not be part of the output then unless they're grouping columns.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It sounds like there is no built-in way to do this in `dplyr`, if I understand correctly.  @akrun, what do you mean by use `Map`?  I could not find any reference to such a function or argument.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following: here I would like to apply min function to one variable and max function to other. Then I simply merge those with the grouping variable.

```
> by_species <- iris %>% group_by(Species)
```

Start with variable for which I want to apply the min function:

> min_var <- by_species %>% summarise_each(funs(min), Petal.Width)
>   min_var
>       Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

```
      Species Petal.Width
       (fctr)       (dbl)
1     setosa         0.1
2 versicolor         1.0
3  virginica         1.4
```

Then the variable for which I want to apply the max function:

> max_var <- by_species %>% summarise_each(funs(max), Sepal.Width)
>   max_var
>       Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

```
     Species Sepal.Width
      (fctr)       (dbl)
 1     setosa         4.4
 2 versicolor         3.4
 3  virginica         3.8
```

Now, we just merge the above two:

> left_join(min_var,max_var)
>       Joining by: "Species"
>       Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

```
      Species Petal.Width Sepal.Width
     (fctr)       (dbl)       (dbl)
1     setosa         0.1         4.4
2 versicolor         1.0         3.4
3  virginica         1.4         3.8
```

Comment: Thanks Rushad.  This is exactly the alternate solution that I was referring to in option (2) above.  It is what I am currently using, but thanks for the detailed response. +1